# Schengen Visa : Tourism and Meeting friends

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, tourist-visas

My main purpose of travel to Schengen region is Tourism and I am going to mention the same in my application.
I might also look to meet some friends. However its more like if they have time, we might meet and travel around. Still for transparency purpose, I want to specify that in my application.
Does the application requires full details about friends if my main purpose if tourism and trip is fully self sponsored.

As trip is fully sponsored by me, I don't see it necessary but need some inputs on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional column in Schengen visa for comments (or attach a cover letter). You can just mention like this. Your main purpose is tourism. You will be meeting friends who are there, if you get time. No need to provide details of friends, unless you plan to stay with them for any amount of time.

Note that you have to provide a detailed itinerary, like where you are staying, how you are traveling inside the Schengen area, modes of transportation (with tickets) and dates. A cover letter with clear itinerary will make everything clear and will increase your chance to get visa and avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you for details. I will not stay with them but if they get time/leaves and we explore city together then they might stay with me and I have booked accommodation mentioning occupancy 2-3. So I  
 want to mention all details for Visa officer. However even if they stay with me, I don't see need for mentioning details about them.

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut No need to mention that. Don't create confusion in the visa application. Make the details clear. That's all.